# Vertex Normal Algorithm Optimization

Tags: c, normals

I have a simple algorithm for calculating vertex normals. For a large number of vertexes the algorithm is too slow to be useful. My question is if there is a better way of calculating vertex normals.(face vertices are already calculated)

The code I am using is below:

```
vec3 vn;
vec3 vna[object.vertexNumber];
for(int i = 0; i < object.vertexNumber; i++)
{
    vec3 tempvn = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0};
    vn = object.points[i];
    for(int j = 0; j < object.vertexNumber; j++)
    {
        if(vn.x == object.points[j].x && vn.y == object.points[j].y && vn.z == object.points[j].z)
        {
            tempvn = plusequalvec3(tempvn, object.normals[j]);
        }
    }
    vna[i] = normalizevec3(tempvn);
}
```

Comment: If code does not have -0.0 nor NaN, could use `memcmp(&vn, &object.points[j], sizeof vn)`  Faster?  IDK YMMV

Comment: Looks like code could halve things by assessing the upper-right diagonal  of the matrix  and the diagonal rather than the whole square of the matrix.